# What is more preferable, one storyboard many viewController OR many storyboard with each have one viewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to iOS and Xcode.

I saw several projects and there is two way to show their apps:

**case 1**
One storyboard and many viewControllers

**case 2**
Many storyboard and each has only one viewController

is this make some difference in performance?
or just do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a question of organization. There is no meaningful difference in performance.

A big argument for lots of storyboards is source control. Xcode does not know how to track changes to Storyboard files, and if multiple developers edit the same storyboard in a project under source control, there **will** be merge conflicts. Fixing those conflicts often requires editing the raw XML format contents of the storyboards, which is a horrible mess.

If you break down your storyboards such that each one contains a small related group of view controllers, you can avoid having multiple team members making editing the same storyboard and getting into merge conflict hell.